# KeyboardAvoidingView doesn't do anything

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to work with the KeyboardAvoidingView component from react native but it doesn't seem to do anything. Here is my code :

```
    <Container>
      <Header navigation={this.props.navigation} title="Header" />
      <View style={{height: pageHeight}}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex: 1,}} behaviour="padding" enabled>
          <ScrollView style={{
            flex: 1,
            borderColor: '#F00',
            borderWidth: 2,
          }} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 1" editable={true} />
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 2" editable={true} />
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 3" editable={true} />
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 4" editable={true} />
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 5" editable={true} />
          </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    </Container>
```

And here is the result [when the keybaord is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7F3e.png) and [when the keyboard is open on the 5th item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5VPP.png). As you can see nothing happens, the view doesn't move a bit. What's weird is that I can add a paddingBottom to the KeyboardAvoidingView and it works fine and it allows me to [mimic the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y3j6.png).

Is there something missing in my code ?

Comment: Have you tried to change behaviour (values are position, height and padding)?

Comment: Yes I tried everything and it never moves. I'm using expo version 26 and react native version 0.54

Comment: I think that i have understood what's the problem. Put the KeyboardAvoidingView inside the ScrollView and let me know.

Comment: It may seem like something obvious to check but the spelling of behavior vs behaviour might help.  I'm keeping my fingers crossed for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this without `KeyboardAvoidingView` to move your screen while opening keyboard

```
<Container>
    <Header navigation={this.props.navigation} title="Header" />
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
        <View style={{height: pageHeight, flex: 1,  borderColor: '#F00', borderWidth: 2,}}>
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 1" editable={true} />
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 2" editable={true} />
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 3" editable={true} />
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 4" editable={true} />
            <InputWithLabel label="Item 5" editable={true} />
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</Container>
```

Comment: The result is the same, the 5th item is blocked by the keyboard when it opens.

Comment: try removing height from scrollview and add it into View it may works

Comment: Ok that worked thanks a lot, but I can't figure out why ?

Comment: May be because its considers overflow property of view when keyboard hides some space of screen, I am not 100% sure about this, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either KeyboardAvoidingView or Scrollview in your code. Not both.

Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file which will be inside your project folder in following path /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

You find the line **android:windowSoftInputMode** and change it's value as 
**adjustPan**.

So when you tap on item #5 your view will be above the keypad.

Comment: I tried using a regular view and with no other view inside the KeyboardAvoidingView, it didn't change anything the problem remains the same.

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file